# Spring Batch reading half data when field used to query with Reader is being updated with Writer

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a peculiar problem with my Spring Boot batch processing Job.

The Job reads only half the data from MongoDB, and with each subsequent run it reads half the remaining data (e.g. 30k -> 15k -> 7.5k...), and it finally finishes when there's sub 1000 documents remaining since I set `cursorBatchSize(1000)` in my `ItemReader`.

The issue occurs because my `ItemReader` queries for all documents that do not have the attribute `processedAt`. It then passes them onto the `ItemReader`, which processes them and adds the `processedAt` attribute to the documents, and then saves hem inside the *same* collection the reader is currently going through.

I wrote an entirely new SpringBoot application to recreate this, removed everything that's irrelevant to the issue, minimized all data models, etc., so there's nothing custom about the Job or Batch config.

It doesn't look like a memory issue since when I run it with the query parameters set to return all documents it works fine.

I don't think it's a race condition since the issue persists after setting `throttleLimit(1)` or specifying a TaskExecutor with only 1 Thread.

The Document in question only has 2 fields: a `name` attribute and a `processedAt` attribute, which isn't appended onto it until the document has been successfully processed.

Here's the `ItemReader`:

```
    @Bean(name = "myReader")
    @StepScope
    public MongoItemReader<TroublesomeModel> reader() {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("processedAt").exists(false));

        query.noCursorTimeout();
        query.cursorBatchSize(1000);

        MongoItemReader<TroublesomeModel> reader = new MongoItemReader<>();
        reader.setTemplate(mongoTemplate);
        reader.setTargetType(TroublesomeModel.class);
        reader.setSaveState(false);
        reader.setQuery(query);

        return reader;
    }
```

The `ItemWriter`:

```
    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends TroublesomeModel> items) {
        BulkOperations bulkOperations = mongoTemplate.bulkOps(BulkOperations.BulkMode.UNORDERED, TroublesomeModel.class);

        for (TroublesomeModel item: items) {
            item.setAsProcessed();
            bulkOperations.updateMulti(
                    Query.query(Criteria.where("_id").is(item.getId())),
                    new Update().set("processedAt", item.getProcessedAt())
            );
        }

        bulkOperations.execute();
    }

    @Bean(name = "myWriter")
    @StepScope
    public ItemWriter<TroublesomeModel> writer() {
        return new BatchItemWriterConfig(mongoTemplate);
    }
```

And the `Job` and `Step` configuration:

```
    @Bean(name = "myStep")
    public Step step(
            @Qualifier("myReader") MongoItemReader<TroublesomeModel> myReader,
            @Qualifier("myWriter") ItemWriter<? super TroublesomeModel> myWriter
    ) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
                .<TroublesomeModel, TroublesomeModel>chunk(100) // has to be 100
                .reader(myReader)
                .writer(myWriter)
                .throttleLimit(10)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "myJob")
    public Job myJob(@Qualifier("myStep") Step step) {
        return jobBuilderFactory
                .get(JOB_NAME)
                .start(step)
                .build();
    }
```

Is my current logic just not feasible to implement or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: It is not clear how you run jobs to process half the dataset each time. Are those different job instances? Updating flags on items would cause an issue with paging readers, but should work fine with cursor-based readers like in your case. Is there another process updating items while the batch job is processing them? A minimal example that reproduces the issue would be helpful to help you efficiently: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: Unless you specify otherwise (`spring.batch.job.enabled=false` ) they will run once on their own. Or you could set an `@Scheduled` parameter on an extra `MyJobRunner` class that will run and re-run the job. Both ways reproduce the same result, so I let Spring automatically start it upon application launch. To "restart" the job I just restart the application (or scheduler does it in the other case).

There is nothing else doing anything, the only thing in my application is the batch job config and database model. Short of providing a github link, there is no more info to provide.

Comment: And what is the issue? Is the fact that the job is reading half the data each new run what you consider an issue? That is a design decision IMO, not related to spring batch, and is not necessarily an issue. A spring batch job is expected to process a fixed data set. If you change the input during the processing, it should not be surprising that next executions process more or less data, depending on filtering criteria given to the reader and data modification implemented in the processor.

Comment: Doesn't the reader execute the query for each new set of data if I configure the cursor to have a specified batch size? I enabled detailed logs on mongodb and I could see that it was executing new queries. I am confused as to why it would always process exactly half of the data if it kept making new queries.

Comment: I guess it process half-data because each run it changes the processAt, so the next run it will select less data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was, and it's caused by the way `ItemReader` fetches new data.

I logged every query on the database and came upon this line:

```
{ find: "message", filter: { processedAt: { $exists: false } },
skip: 8190, limit: 10, batchSize: 1000, noCursorTimeout: true, $db: ...
```

The interaction between `skip` and `filter` causes data to be skipped because once an item has been processed (and marked as such in the database) it is no longer returned by the `filter`-query. That means that when `skip` is called on the query, it is skipping over *unprocessed data* since the processed data was excluded from the query.

**The conclusion from this is that it is not possible to update the data while it is being processed.**

---

The workaround I used was to remove the query parameter for `processedAt` and create a new `ItemProcessor` that checks if the item has been processed before passing it on to `ItemWriter`. The efficiency of this is questionable. If you expect the query to return mostly data that is valid for processing (i.e. without the `processedAt` field), then it's a good solution. If you expect a lot of data is going to be discarded because it already has a `processedAt` flag, then you might want to look into other solutions (and please do share them if you figure something out).

This is what the `ItemProcessor` looks like, nothing fancy:

```
public class MyItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<TroublesomeModel, TroublesomeModel> {
    @Override
    public TroublesomeModel process(TroublesomeModel item) throws Exception {
        if (item.getProcessedAt() != null) {
            return null;
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

And since I am using `BulkOperations` in my `ItemWriter` which cannot handle empty lists, there needs to be a null check before entering it as well.

---

An alternative workaround would be to just execute the query as-is, with the `processedAt` flag, set a `reader.maxItemCount` to a low enough number (in my case 1000), and re-run the job inside a scheduler on repeat. This fits my use case since it's supposed to actively process data as it arrives. No data is duplicated and it doesn't cause any unnecessary data processing or lengthy database queries.